# Validation error on Nu HTML Checker: "Bad value radio for attribute type on element input."

Tags: html, w3c-validation, wai-aria

I am getting this error

> Error: Bad value radio for attribute type on element input.

when trying to validate the following HTML on https://validator.w3.org/nu/#file

```
<fieldset>
<p class="city" id="citypref">Generally, I would prefer to live in...</p>
<br>
<label for="la" id="laLabel">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="city" id="la" value="la" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="laLabel" role="radiogroup" >Los Angeles, California</label>
<br>
<label for="boston" id="bostonLabel">
<input type="radio" name="city" id="boston" value="boston" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="bostonLabel" role="radiogroup" >Boston, Massachusetts</label>
<br>
<label for="both" id="bothLabel">
<input type="radio" name="city" id="both" value="both" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="bothLabel" role="radiogroup" >Both</label>
<br>
<label for="neither" id="neitherLabel">
<input type="radio" name="city" id="neither" value="neither" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="neitherLabel" role="radiogroup" >Neither</label>
<br>
</fieldset>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

> It seems that https://validator.w3.org/ is not yet equipped with the
>   following codes

It implements the conformance requirements for use of ARIA in HTML defined in https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/ which [prohibits `role=radiogroup` on `input type="radio"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#input-radio). It defines what the valid role values are for all elements. No `input` elements allow `role="radio"`. Only `role="menuitemradio"` is allowed for `input type="radio"`.

Another answer incorrectly suggested `ul role="radiogroup"` and `li role="radio"` instead. But ARIA in HTML [prohibits `role="radiogroup"` for `ul`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#ul) and [prohibits `role="radio"` for `li`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#li).

Note there are some roles and property attributes introduced in ARIA 1.1 that the validator does not recognise. This is being worked on.

If you have an issue with the w3c validator suggest [filing an issue](https://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html#issues)

Answer (score 1):

<s>It seems that https://validator.w3.org/ is not yet equipped with the following codes:</s>

```
aria-required="false"
aria-labelledby="neitherLabel"
role="radiogroup"
```

<s>As soon as you delete them, your code will pass without any problems.</s>

W3 website provided examples on how to use the previous 3 codes on this page: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA2.html.
This is one of the examples that they provided:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="alerts1">
<label for="acctnum" data-required="true">Account Number</label>
<input size="12" type="text" id="acctnum"
  aria-required="true" name="acctnum" />

<p id="radio_label" data-required="true">Please send an alert when balance exceeds $3,000.</p>

<ul  id="rg" role="radiogroup" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="radio_label">
<li id="rb1" role="radio">Yes</li>
<li id="rb2" role="radio">No</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

When I copied their own `example` and pasted it on their validator, it failed to pass, and gave me the same error message that you are receiving.

Therefore, I would suggest contacting them directly to ask them <s>to add the previous 3 codes to their validator database as a valid usage.</s>

**Update:**

Check out Steve's answer for clarification.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thank you for the feedback, what about the `ul` and `li` tags? The validator does not seem to accept it in my experiment.

Comment: See Steve’s revised answer: ARIA in HTML [prohibits `role="radiogroup"` for `ul`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#ul) and [prohibits `role="radio"` for `li`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#li). So  [that example in the *Techniques for WCAG 2.0* document](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA2.html#ARIA2-ex3) is wrong—that’s a bug in the *Techniques for WCAG 2.0* doc. The only normative (formal/official) source of rules on the use of ARIA in HTML is the actual [ARIA in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria) spec. Any examples elsewhere should be checked against the rules in that spec.