# HTML validator attribute error

Tags: html

[HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) (Links to an external site.) is giving following error types on my form HTML however below code looks fine to me; please suggest if I may be looking over something obvious:

- **Bad value radio for attribute type on element input**:
  input type="radio" name="customer" value="new" checked aria-checked="true" aria-labelledby="print" role="radiogroup" aria-required="false"
- **Attribute checked not allowed on element input at this point**: input type="radio" name="customer" value="new" checked aria-checked="true" aria-labelledby="print" role="radiogroup" aria-required="false"
- **Attribute aria-checked not allowed on element input at this point**: input type="radio" name="customer" value="new" checked aria-checked="true" aria-labelledby="print" role="radiogroup" aria-required="false"

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/019fzygc/

```
<legend>Survey</legend>
            <p id="repeat">Have you ordered from this site before?</p>
            <label><input type="radio" name="customer" value="new" checked aria-checked="true" aria-labelledby="print" role="radiogroup" aria-required="false"> No</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="customer" value="existing" aria-labelledby="print" aria-checked="false" role="radiogroup" aria-required="false"> Yes</label>
```

EDIT: I am not using ul / li on my code here unlike the below suggested question.

Comment: You have to notice that any type of HTML you have used.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer @SaidbakR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation error on Nu HTML Checker: "Bad value radio for attribute type on element input."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446061/validation-error-on-nu-html-checker-bad-value-radio-for-attribute-type-on-elem)

Comment: I mean what is  the HTML version you have defined your HTML document with? @user7055533